# To create a special matrix !!

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, transpose

How to create a $N \times N$ matrix with $1$ and $-1$ as its elements, such that when this matrix is multiplied with its transpose the resultant matrice is $N \times \mathbb{I}_N$.
Where $N$ is a scalar and $\mathbb{I}_N$ is the $N \times N$ identity matrix.
Examle for 2x2 matrix
$-1$ $1$
$1$ $1$

Example for 4x4 matrix
$-1$ $1$ $1$ $1$
 $1$ $-1$ $1$ $1$
 $1$ $1$ $-1$ $1$
 $1$ $1$ $1$ $-1$

Comment: Have you found a 2x2 example? There aren't that many combinations, so you can try by hand and maybe figure out a pattern.

Comment: Yes i have found out a 2x2 and 4x4 example but can't figure out any pattern.

Comment: It would make sense to include those examples in your question then. It's encouraged at MSE to show your work so we can figure out where you are in the problem, and try to answer accordingly. Not that I have an answer to this one yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some $N$, this is known to be impossible. For some other specific values of $N$, there are known ways of construction. Yet, in general, no one knows how to do it or if such a matrix exists.

See [Hadamard matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix) on Wikipedia.